# Communicating IoT Device with Google CLoud/Firebase using SSL

Tags: firebase, ssl, google-cloud-platform, openssl, sim800

I have 2G GSM Module SIM808 which supports HTTPS using SSL but doesn't support TLS.
I am trying to connect to HTTPS website but in return HTTP code 606 is received.
So how do we directly or indirectly connect the GSM module to Google Cloud so that it can access firebase and update/get entries in the database

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Firebase only supports TLS 1.2 or later which is not supported by SIM80x.

What you can do here is to use your 2G module in PPP/PPPoS mode rather than AT command mode.

This way a full TCP/IP (including TLS1.2) will be implemented in your host microcontroller and your 2G module will only forward the frames to the 2G network.

A common way to do this is to use LwIP(TCP/IP stack) + mbedTLS(TLS library)

[How to enter PPP mode](https://maxwellweru.com/sim900-dial-up-connection-setup-4261476bbd21)

[PPPOS implementation of stm32f4-discovery](https://habr.com/ru/post/419037/)